Bash Function to auto save and quit vim when it's opened as the default editor
I frequently do the git commit --amend command which opens vim then i save and quit with :wq. I am trying to make a bash function that will do this for me. I am having trouble finding any documentation or info about how to preempt input into vim.
That being said i do have another (arguably better) solution
commitUpdate() {  
  git commit --amend -m "$(git log -1 --pretty=%B)"
  git push -f
}

But now i'm still left wondering how to send commands to vim when it is opened as the default editor by a CLI tool? Thank you!

Have you considered using git commit --amend --no-edit?

I didn't realize that was an option facepalm the docs for amend would have been a good place to start!

--no-edit is definitely the way to go, but to answer your title question, you can do EDITOR="touch" somecommand to change your editor to something non-interactive for a single command.

"When all else fails RTFM." ;)

@ReckerDan Speaking of documentation: Since you are wrapping git commands in bash functions, are you aware of git aliases? Might be useful, if not now maybe at some point.

Thank you all! "that other guy"'s answer fits the bill! I love git aliases and use them!

"that other guy" gave the answer in the comments. As skipping an editor ad-hoc is what i'm looking to do in the grand scheme of things. Thank you!
EDITOR="touch" <do whatever>

